# Configuration of network_security_config

Tags: android, xml, security, android-manifest

I follow this guide to configurate "network_security_config" https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config?hl=es-419 and don't work for me. The app response all the domains and certifcates, not only the configurated in "network_security_config"

In the AndroidManifest.xml, i added `<application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />`

And there is my network_security_config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
  <domain-config>
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">mysite.com</domain>
    <trust-anchors>
      <certificates src="@raw/comodo"/>
    </trust-anchors>
  </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Please add the logcat messages related to this

Comment: Hi, I can't find anything related to network configuration, can you give me some advice to search?